# Look for Basic Introduction of TCP/IP in C++

Tags: tcp

I am looking for a primer to learn TCP/IP basic knowledge.

Can someone give me some suggestions on books or online resources?

thank you

// Update the title based on comments

Comment: Tag your question a little better! C programming? Python? Delphi?

Comment: @karlphillip, I have specified my interested field . thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two books that I used in my studies:

[http://www.amazon.com/Computer-Networking-Top-Down-Approach-5th/dp/0136079679/ref=dp_ob_title_bk](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0136079679)

[http://www.amazon.com/Internetworking-TCP-IP-Vol-5th/dp/0131876716/ref=dp_ob_title_bk/184-0356931-5226767](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131876716)

Answer (score 3):

[Beej's Guide to Network Programming](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/)

Answer (score 2):

Stevens' [TCP/IP Illustrated](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201633469) is still a very good resource to learn the basics of protocols.

Answer (score 0):

The [TCP](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc793.html) and [IP](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc791.html) RFCs are good places to look if you want dense information. Once you're ready to start playing with packets, [Scapy](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/) is an amazingly great tool.